Posts that incorporate the "voltage" tag appear to be greyed out in the home or question list
If I look down the list of questions on the home or question page, those questions that contain the voltage tag appear to be greyed out as per the top two on this page: -

Notice also that the 2nd one from the top has had an answer accepted by the OP yet the green box that normally surrounds the answer-tally box is not present.
This has been bugging me for maybe a year now but I thought I'd mention it because it now is apparent that it's related to any question containing the "voltage" tag (I checked 5 pages of questions).
Why does this happen?


Why does this happen?

This "crossed-out eye" symbol next to the voltage tag (here copied from your question):

means you have chosen to ignore the voltage tag in your settings. That means everything with the voltage tag is dimmed to reduce the visual impact (since you have selected to ignore that tag). That includes not having the visual impact of the green box on a question with an accepted answer.
When I look at the same question, since I have not selected to ignore questions with the voltage tag, I see something different (i.e. normal) and I do see the green box for that question, due to it having an accepted answer:

Notice the lack of a "crossed-out eye" next to the voltage tag, since I do not have that one set to ignore.
You can edit your watched & ignored tags, on the site home page, right side column. AFAIK mods can't change that for you.
